# I am having trouble with writing ScriptRunner Behaviours

Tags: groovy, jira

I am trying to set two behaviors, but it is very hard because I do not have any coding background. The idea is that the ticket creation screen would hide/show fields depending on what the user chooses.

So the first behavior should be from a dropdown menu with 3 options (SAP, Jira, Other) and the dropdown menu's name is Affected Software. If the user chooses SAP, a textfield to appear which is called Transaction number. If they choose other, another textfield should appear called Please enter software name and otherwise, these should be hidden and not show any other fields.

Here is the code I tried to write:

```
import com.onresolve.jira.groovy.user.FormField

FormField dropDown = getFieldByName("Affected Software")
FormField other = getFieldByName("Transaction Number")
FormField other = getFieldByName("Please enter software name")

if (dropdown.getFormValue() == 'SAP') {
    other.setHidden(false)
    other.setFormValue("SAP chosen")
} if else (dropdown.getFormValue() == "Other")
    other.setHidden(false) 
    other.setFormValue("Other chosen")
else {
 other.setHidden(true)
}
```

The second behavior is a bit simpler. There is again a dropdown field called Is there a workaround with these options(yes, no, I don't know). If the user chooses yes, a field should show up called Explain the workaround.  Otherwise nothing should change.

This is the code I tried to write for that one

```
import com.onresolve.jira.groovy.user.FormField

FormField dropDown = getFieldByName("Is there a workaround?")
FormField other = getFieldByName("Explain the workaround")

if (dropdown.getFormValue() == 'yes') {
    other.setHidden(false)
    other.setFormValue("yes chosen")
} else {
 other.setHidden(true)
}
```

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for getValue() rather then getFormValue() as this will give you the ID of the underlying value, like an option ID.

Comment: and it is never a good idea to initialize one variable twice